# Deploying a React + NodeJS + Express + MySQL App to Heroku only deploying the Server Not the React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

As the Title States I have a React + NodeJS + Express + MySQL that we are trying to deploy to a Heroku webpage. I have it set to auto deploy every time something is pushed to the master branch of GitHub.

The issue that we are running into is it is deploying the routes for the server and displaying all of the correct information but the react app isn't displaying at all. How can I make it so that the server routes aren't showing but the react frontend is?

Attached is the code for the Server.js as well as the script that I am running to build the client.

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


const homeRoute = require("./routes/home");
const allReviews = require("./routes/getAllReviews");
const mostRecentReviews = require("./routes/mostRecentReview");
const postReview = require("./routes/postReview");
const editReview = require("./routes/editReview");
const updateReview = require("./routes/updateReview");
const deleteReview = require("./routes/deleteReview");
const filterReview = require("./routes/getFilterReview");
const recentReviews = require("./routes/mostRecentReview");

const locationAverageRating = require("./routes/locationAverageRating");
const allLocations = require('./routes/allLocations');

app.use(cors())

app.use('/', homeRoute);
app.use('/review', allReviews);
app.use('/locations', allLocations);
app.use('/review/recent', mostRecentReviews);
app.use('/review/post', postReview);

app.use('/review/edit', editReview);
app.use('/review/update', updateReview);
app.use('/review/delete', deleteReview);
app.use('/review/filter', filterReview);
app.use('/carrier/recent',recentReviews);

app.use('/carrier/edit', editReview);

app.use('/carrier/locations', locationAverageRating);

app.use(express.static('client/build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname + "./client/build/index.html"));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

Heroku build script:

```
  "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Thank you in advance for the help and if you need any other files or have any questions feel free to reach out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `app.use` the order matters. Because all of the server routes are declared before the route to the react build, the server routes will take precedence.

Consider prefixing the server routes with something that distinguishes them from requests that should be handled by your front end build (`/api` is a common choice).

Another option would be to specify a route for your front end (`/app` maybe). You could redirect certain `GET` requests to this route inside your `homeRoute` so that if someone visits your site from the root URL, they end up in the right place (assuming you don't have other `GET` routes that you want `homeRoute` to handle).

So you could change the wildcard `GET` route to look something like this:

```
app.get('/app*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname + "./client/build/index.html"));
})
```

and then inside 'homeRoutes'

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/app')
})
...other homeRoutes
```

Comment: This is a blog post I referred to many times when I was doing something similar about a year ago, you may also find it useful: https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look into this solution and get back to you!